# how to define webservice end point url

Tags: java, web-services, websphere, jax-ws

I am new to webservice. I have created a webservice with following WSDL definiton.

```
 <wsdl:service name="InterfaceService">

    <wsdl:port name="InterfaceSOAP"
        binding="impl1InterfaceSOAP">
        <soap:address
            location="http://localhost:9080/MyWeb/services/MyInterface" />
    </wsdl:port>
 </wsdl:service>
```

When the webservice is published the webservice is available at URL http://localhost:9080/MyWeb/InterfaceService instead of http://localhost:9080/MyWeb/services/MyInterface URl. 
How can we change the URL where the webservice is getting published

Comment: Is this in WebSphere Liberty, or WebSphere Application Server traditional?

Answer (score 0):

### In WebSphere Application Server traditional

#### Use a custom url-pattern in web.xml

E.g.

### web.xml

```
<servlet id="...">
    <servlet-name>mypkg.MyInterface</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>mypkg.MyInterface</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mypkg.MyInterface</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/MyInterface</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

See official doc [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCKBL_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twbs_customwebxml.html)

### In WebSphere Liberty

#### Use a  element in ibm-ws-bnd.xml

E.g.

### ibm-ws-bnd.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<webservices-bnd xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-ws-bnd_1_0.xsd" 
    version="1.0">
    <webservice-endpoint port-component-name="MyInterface" address="/services/MyInterface" />
</webservices-bnd>
```

See official doc [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_dep_jaxws_binding.html)

Comment: I was asking for wbsphere  application server. But i thought for jax ws we don't have to define service in web.xml. is it like if v don't define then default address s taken? And even if I define the error displayed is MyInterface s not a servlet

Comment: Yes, you can use the JAX-WS annotations and as I understand it, a default web.xml will be generated for you during deploy.  The default URL pattern would be **/MyInterface**.     But then you can customize the web.xml as I mentioned for things like URL mapping.    If you're still having problems, let me ask: did you update the **<servlet-class>** in my snippet to point to your actual package and class?

Comment: Yes, I have added the correct servlet-class. I have a question regarding the xsi:schemalocation in webservices.xml. What version do i have to specify for jax-ws. Currenlty the version is 1.1.

Comment: Not sure what version of WebSphere you're running on or what you're trying to do.   Are you having a problem with what you're using?    But the EE 6 level schemalocation info seems to be: `xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_web_services_1_3.xsd"`